# Select objects or elements of auocad dwg file

Tags: ui-automation, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I have a situation where i want to crop ,cut or select the objects of dwg file & save in new file. I have came up with drawing an polygon using markup feature of auto desk forge but now i want to select or crop the area within the polygon, is there any way possible to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To create a second `.dwg` with the cropped objects you can use [Design Automation](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v2), which allow you to open the file and copy the objects you need using AutoCAD engine.

Note that on Viewer there is a **dbId**, but this is not valid on AutoCAD. Instead you need to get the `externalId`, which should be the respective `Handle`. Then, on Design Automation, get objectId from it. [See more here](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/02/getting_access_.html).